# CakePHP Query - Conditional Based on Contain Field

Tags: cakephp, associations, filtering, cakephp-3.0, query-builder

I am developing a system that holds reports from customer's computers and displays failures in a list.  I am attempting to write a query that locates all systems that have currently failed or have failures in the past.

My model for `Computers` has a field that says `last_report_pass` that allows me to quickly find computers that failed on the current day.  My `Reports` are associated with a computer ID and has a field called `status` that says whether it was a pass or fail.

I am attempting to write a query that will only show `last_report_pass` being `0`, or failed, or show it if it has reports that were found and joined (meaning there were previous failures).

Here was my idea:

```
$computers = $this->Computers->find('all', [
    'conditions' => [
        'last_report_pass' => '0',
        'COUNT(Reports) NOT' => '0'
    ],
    'contain' => [
        'Reports' => [
            'conditions' => [
                'status' => '0'
            ]
        ]
);
```

I do not know what to do from here.  I could probably write this in SQL but am trying to stick with Cake's ORM Query Builder. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd probably use a counter cache to count these ... it'd be easily the simplest answer and you would then store the number of reports in the Computers table which would be handy in other ways too perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `matching`
its similar to contain, but it will filter by associated data:

It will be something like this

```
$query->distinct(['Computers.id'])
    ->matching('Reports', function ($q) {
        return $q->where(['Reports.last_report_pass' => 0]);
    });
```

Its important to notice that you will also have to `contain` the `Reports` table if you need to display some data which is on this table.

[Reference](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#filtering-by-associated-data)

Comment: I tried using matching and it duplicated the Computer for every matched report.  Is there a way to do this so the reports with last_report_pass 0 are contained in a sub array as it is with a regular contain?

Comment: Edited the original post, added the distinct clause, guess may work